# Lubuntu 14.10 won't update or shutdown

Tags: lubuntu, 14.10, shutdown, administration, privileges

I started up my computer and used the terminal to check some network settings, but when I tried to turn it off again, a message shows up at the bottom of the shut down menu:

```
"GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Operation not permitted"
```

I figured it had something to do with needing to update, but when I tried to do that, it gives me the message:

```
You are not allowed to perform this action

You don't have the required privileges to perform this action.
```

Why would it tell me that when I'm the ONLY user!?

I'm currently using **Lubuntu 14.10**, please help me!

Comment: Did you use sudo before your commands?

Comment: It seems you are not so distance from here... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1300798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar problem on Lubuntu 14.04, with the added nuisance of a bunch of error boxes popping up on booting. After a bit of digging, I have concluded that the following might be relevant:

1. `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` is not running (not listed when I run `ps aux | grep pol`). Attempting to start it throws:

   ```
   Cannot register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.NotSupported: Operation not supported
   ```
2. `pkexec` has segfaulted at some point during the boot, and is broken. Running `pkexec echo 'test'` results in a segfault.
3. This line in my auth.log:

   ```
   gnome-keyring-daemon[1255]: couldn't set environment variable in session: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
   ```
4. I have tried the solutions listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303309/cant-mount-usb-devices-shut-down-etc-as-a-user), without success.
5. I have tried reinstalling policykit-1-gnome and gnome-keyring, without success.

Lastly, the only workaround I've found is running `sudo shutdown now` from a terminal.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I don't understand code like most Linux users. It was also so long ago, I'm afraid I can't remember how I fixed it. I think I sudo'd myself and updated from there, then the problem went away. Either way, I'll accept your answer as the solution.